# CGRectGet doesn't work well

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, frame, cgrect

I'm working in Swift with XCode 6 and Sprite Kit and I want to have the biggest pixel in y, so i'm using this function :

```
CGRectGetMaxY(frame)
```

and I tested my code with the iPhone 6 simulator, so the value should be 1334.0 but the console shows me only 667.0 ...

What is wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you're working in "point-space" and not "pixel-space".  Depending on your settings, your image (I'm assuming that's where 1334 comes from) is likely at a `@2x` resolution.

1. Check your assets folder to make sure the image is defined how it should be.
2. Check your `scale` settings
3. UIKit (and most of iOS) runs on point-space, so try to work in these coordinates - they abstract device resolution (important now that we have `@1x, @2x,` and `@3x` devices).

---

Point-space:

The original iPhone was 320x480 pixels.  In order to have your code be device-agnostic, when they went to Retina, the screen and all the logic stayed at a resolution of 320x480.  These didn't always correspond to pixels, so the terminology changes to "points".  That's why when you grab the screen size for an iPhone 4 it still reports 320x480.

[Apple's Documentation on this.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH14-SW14)

Comment: That has nothing to do with `UIFont`. The points that `UIFont` takes in are a whole different measure. Remove the `UIFont` part.